# Help needed in proving non-convexity of the following two variable function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

I have following function $$f(x,y)=x^2\exp(y)$$ Where $x>0$ and $y>0$. The constraint $f(x,y)\leq c$ (where $c$ is some positive value) results in non-convex set. If I am able to prove that $f(x,y)$ is concave then I can understand how the constraint results in non-convex set. To prove that $f(x,y)$ is concave I get the Hessian of the $f(x,y)$ as follows $$H(x,y)=\left[\begin{matrix}2\exp(y) & 2x\exp(y) \\ 2x\exp(y) & x^2\exp(y) \end{matrix}\right]$$ Now for any real valued vector $\textbf{v}=[v_1 \quad v_2]$ if $$\textbf{v}H(x,y)\textbf{v}^T\leq 0$$ then it means that $f(x,y)$ is concave. But I get $$\textbf{v}H(x,y)\textbf{v}^T=\exp(y)[2v_1^2+4v_1v_2x+v_2^2x^2]$$ which I think is not always negative. Therefore, How to prove that $f(x,y)$ is a concave function? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _If I am able to prove that $f(x,y)$ is concave then I can understand how the constraint results in non-convex set._ 

Your logic is simply wrong here. Consider $\log(x+y) \leq 1$; the left-hand function is concave, and yet the set is convex, equivalent to the $0< x+y \leq e$.

Comment: You are making the same logical mistake over and over again in these questions, and I really must ask that you stop and consider this carefully. Non-convexity is _never proven constructively_. It is proven effectively by _contradiction_. For convex sets, that means finding a line segment whose endpoints are in the set but whose midpoint (or any other point in the segment) is not, as Kavi did. For functions, there are a variety of approaches, but they all amount to finding a single counterexample to the standard claims of convexity (positive definite Hessian, secants lie above the function).

Comment: @MichaelGrant thank you for your comments. Your example of $\log(x+y)\leq 1$ is very good for understanding. I am actually a beginner who does not know the place from where he can get answers to his basic questions therefore I post these questions. Nevertheless, I will try to minimize my mistakes through some optimization technique but I think its a non-convex optimization problem and NP hard to solve :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner! But you have indeed been making the same mistake multiple times, and it's a relatively basic logic mistake. I don't know where you're getting your test problems from, but if you're going to learn convex optimization I'd strongly recommend working through an existing curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

For any $c>1$ consider the points $(1,\ln c)$ and $(3,\ln (c/9))$. Both these points satisfy $f(x,y) \leq c$ but the mid-point does not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prove that f(x,y) is concave. Indeed, it is not.

Take, for example, x = y = 1. Then the eigenvalues of the Hessian of f(x,y) are -1.526458808 and 9.681304292, which shows that the Hessian is indefinite there.  Therefore, f(x,y) is neither convex nor concave.

Comment: so If I want to show that $f(x,y)\leq c$ results in a non-convex set then plotting a graph of $f(x,y)\leq c$ is the only choice? Right?

Comment: There is no need to "plot" any graphs. For instance, let c = 8.5. Then f(1.2)  = 7.3891 satisfies the constraint. f(3,1) = 8.1548 also satisfies the constraint. But the average of those 2 points, which is a convex combination of them,  does not satisfy the constraint; namely f(2,1.5) = 8.9634. That explicitly demonstrates non-convexity of the constraint.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. You are absolutely right. But as you can see that the choice of $c=8.5$ is very difficult to make. I do not know how in the research papers they abruptly say that the following constraint is non-convex without giving the reason of their assumption. In this particular case suppose if we chose $c=c_1$ which turns out to show that function is convex then it is difficult to say (until we formally prove it). We may have to check a number $c$'s to make a final decision. Thats the problem due to which I asked for theoretical prove (which in this case is not pssibl)

Comment: Pick any positive c. Then points demonstrating the non-convexity of the constraint can be found. If the research papers spelled out every little thing as you seem to want, they would be hundreds or thousands of pages long.  Try working carefully through the first few chapters of https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ in order to solidify your understanding of convexity.